# unzip error [Error: invalid signature: 0xff000001]

Tags: javascript, node.js, unzip

Im using the following library for node unzip 
https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip

The code which I use is

```
var extractor = unzip.Extract({
                path: 'C://TestFolder//TestZip'
            }).on('close', function () {
              console.log("Success to unzip");
            }).on('error', function (err) {
                console.log("error to unzip", err);
            });
            req.pipe(extractor);
```

The problem that In some zip file Im getting the error (in others its works fine)
[Error: invalid signature: 0x8080014]
[Error: invalid signature: 0x83870008]
....

This error doesnt give a lot info...
searching the web I found this 
https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip/issues/41

And install and require the unzip2 package instead of unzip ,
the issue now that Im getting the following error
unzip Error: invalid signature: 0xff000001

I use the same code for unzip and unzip2 (which I provided in the post above),do I need to use it different?  any hints how to solve it?

UPDATE

I send the zip file from postman like following
[image]

Comment: is this error only with one zip? For this particular zip have you added more file(s), after creating the zip?

Comment: @AbhinabaBasu - I've used ~5 zip files which is not having this issue and working just fine. this zip is with different content but any of the ~5 zips that used have diff content...does it answer your question?

Comment: I have only one doubt. After creating this particular zip, have you edited the same like adding/removing or updating content?

Comment: @AbhinabaBasu - this is zip file which Im getting from external usage

Comment: Upload the ZIP, so we can test it. We can help fixing the issue, with reporoducte it...

Comment: @Amina - thanks, for me any other zip lib that can do the job will be OK like adm-zip , can you provide example as solution how to use it?

Comment: I had the same issue, but it disappeared with unzip2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can temporary save the ZIP file on your disk, and then extract it using `adm-zip`.

**Here is a sample code:**

---

### Client Side:

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

---

### Server Side

Using `multer` to save the uploaded file, and `adm-zip` to extract it.
You need to install both:

```
npm install --save multer
npm install --save adm-zip
```

After installing here an example of using them together:

```
var multer=require('multer')   // a module for saving file from form.
var AdmZip = require('adm-zip'); // a module for extracting files
var express=require('express')  // module for receving HTTP traffic
var app=express()

var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

app.post('/upload',upload.single('fileToUpload'),function(req,res){
   console.log('The file uploaded to:' + req.file.path)
   var zip = new AdmZip(req.file.path); 
   zip.extractAllTo( "/detination_folder/");
})
```

Information about the modules I used:

https://github.com/expressjs/multer , https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip

Comment: Hi Amina thanks! Im using express and the file is coming from the req(I use postman to send the zip file as binary to the body),how should I pass it? Here you read it from the ("./input_file.zip"); which is not my case...Thanks you

Comment: I added an option to read the files directyly from the body of the request, instead of from file

Comment: Thanks but the file is not extracted I put my c folder like this    extractAllToAsync(
           "C://TestFolder//TestZip//test",
            true,   //To overwrite or not
            function callback(){})      
}) what should I put in the callback and what is the extractAllToAsync?

Comment: i've also tried             var AdmZip = require('adm-zip');

                var zip = new AdmZip(req.body);
                zip.extractAllTo("C://TestFolder//TestZip//test",true);
which doesnt work... Im using the bodyParser as you write

Comment: The callback it is optional, to let you know when the extract complete. Can you share the form that are you using for uploading? can you use a regular form, (<form><input name=file type=file></form>) for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96477/discussion-between-shopia-t-and-amina).

Comment: if I want to unzip file to my C folder can you please provide the code e2e ?

Comment: If he code not work, please show me the console error log

Comment: Hi Amina 1+ for the support :) please see my update post, I dont use the multer, I use postman to simulate a client which send a zip and I need to unzip it to my c folder when I try   var zip = new AdmZip(req.body); 
   zip.extractAllTo("C://TestFolder//TestZip);  nothing happen and I dont get any error ,what am I missing here? (I try with diffrents zips and same results,any suggestion ?

Answer (score 5):

[Node-unzip2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzip2) patches this problem.

example :

```
var readStream = fs.createReadStream('path/to/archive.zip');
var writeStream = fstream.Writer('output/path');

readStream
  .pipe(unzip.Parse())
  .pipe(writeStream)
```

Comment: The OP mentions using unzip2 in the original question, which is where the error in the title is coming from

Comment: Does it work for you ?Can you please provide the full code that you use, I want to test it :)

Answer (score 2):

Try your unzip solution, but for receiving the binary data, attach this middleware and then get your file from `req.rawBody`:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var data = new Buffer('');
  req.on('data', function(chunk) {
      data = Buffer.concat([data, chunk]);
  });
  req.on('end', function() {
    req.rawBody = data;
    next();
  });
});
```

Comment: HI, does it work for you?  can you provide please the complte code ? and what you put in postman.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @Amina said.

> You can temporary save the ZIP file on your disk, and then extract it

using whatever `unzipper package like unzip,adm-zip,unzip2,unzippy` or whatever you like it.

For some information, My App structure like this below :

```
//App path --> C:\xampp\htdocs\service

service\
    |
    -- tmp\
    |
    -- app.js
    |
    -- index.html
```

You're using unzip2 right ?
Here's my code:

### Server Side:

I'm using `unzip2` to extract the zipFile, you can test it using postman too. Don't forget using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` when you post it. :D

```
var express = require("express");
var fs = require("fs");
var unzip = require("unzip2");
var app = express();

var multer = require("multer");
var multer_dest = multer({dest: "./tmp"}).single('zipFile');

app.post("/upload_zip",multer_dest,function(req,res){
    console.log(req.file);      
    fs.createReadStream(req.file.path).pipe(unzip.Extract({path: 'C:\\TestFolder\\TestZip'}));
    result = {
        file:req.file,
        message:"File has been extracted"
    };
    fs.unlink(req.file.path, function (e) {
        if (e) throw e;
        console.log('successfully deleted '+req.file.path);
    });
    res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
});

var server = app.listen(8081,function(){
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log("Example App Listening at http://%s:%s",host,port);
})
```

Output :
[image: Output From Postman]

Comment: Thanks Im trying to work with your example1. where should I put theenctype="multipart/form-data" I use postman, can you provide screenshot please . 2. I want to save it in my local folder on C drive('C://TestFolder//TestZip') how I should do that ?im using windows...

Comment: when I use your program as is I got error  Error: Unexpected field
    at makeError (c:\Users\i026\WebstormProjects\extractFileDemo\node_modules\multer\lib\make-error.js:12:13)
    at wrappedFileFilter (c:\Users\i06\WebstormProjects\extractFileDemo\node_modules\multer\index.js:39:19)

Comment: I'm using windows too. Your zipfile is that encrypted ? And please provide your app structure, and i'll check it for you.

Comment: I've updated my answer to extract it in local folder `C:\\TestFolder\\TestZip`, and give some info in postman screenshot.